# Add prefix to all file names in a folder with a certain extension using C#

Tags: c#, directory, filenames, rename, prefix

I have 4 directories that host different files in them.
I currently have a form that if a certain checkbox is checked, it is suppose to go to that directory, and find all the pdf's in that directory and add a prefix to them.

for example, say folder 1 has 5 pdf's in them. i want it to go through and add "some prefix" to the file name.
Before: Filename
After: Some Prefix Filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get all the files in the directory using [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- For each file create a new file path using parent directory path, prefix string and file name
- Use [`File.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to rename the file.

It should be like:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\yourFolder", "*.pdf");
string prefix = "SomePrefix";
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string newFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), (prefix + Path.GetFileName(file)));
    File.Move(file, newFileName);
}
```

Comment: This worked great! I should have clarified something else though, if the file  already has that prefix, it should skip it and keep going.  
Any help with that?

Comment: just before setting `newFileName` check `if(Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith(prefix))` and ignore those files

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = "Some Directory";
string prefix = "Some Prefix";

foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf"))
{
    var newName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), prefix + Path.GetFileName(file));
    File.Move(file, newName);
}
```